# Express: session store, query session key Redis

Tags: node.js, express, session, redis, node.js-connect

```
app.use(express.session({
      store: new RedisStore({
        host: 'localhost',
        port: 6379,
        db: 0,
        pass: 'RedisPASS'
      }),
      secret: '1234567890QWERTY'
    }));
```

The above creates a session store in Redis. But the entry of session data is in some random key like `sess:0t-8-qJG5s0e3w4oGhBjxgAH`. What is best way to get the key of the session established?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do the trick:

```
var key = req.sessionStore.prefix + req.sessionID;
```

(obviously you need to run this code in a middleware or a route handler)

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use a different prefix than `sess` do it like this:

```
app.use(express.session({
      store: new RedisStore({
        host: 'localhost',
        port: 6379,
        db: 0,
        pass: 'RedisPASS',
        prefix: 'mycustomprefix'
      }),
      secret: '1234567890QWERTY'
}));
```